# yum: command not found when building Dockerfile

Tags: docker, yum

The top of my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/provided

ENV R_VERSION=4.3.0

RUN yum -y install wget git tar
```

The other day, all was working fine when I built the container.

However, I updated Docker yesterday, and now I am getting the error "yum: command not found".

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is hard to say whether this worked in the past. If it did, then the image was changed. This is one of the reasons we use tags - or even better hashes - to pin exact versions of images.

Comment: Looks like `yum` was replaced with `microdnf`